# How to make a subString from another string by searching for certain characters

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String x = "ID:12 Patient Name:...";    
String z = = x.substring(3, x.indexOf(' P'));
```

I want to get the ID number

Comment: Please be more elaborate.

Comment: wht is the ID number in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just use something like this:-

```
String z = x.substring(x.indexOf("ID:")+3, x.indexOf("Patient")-1);
```

`+3` - Because you don't need the `ID:`

`-1` - Because you don't need the space before the Patient

This is taking into account that there is a **SINGLE** space before `Patient`, if not,  as **@BuhakeSindi** suggested use the `trim()` method like this:-

```
String z = x.substring(x.indexOf("ID:")+3, x.indexOf("Patient"));
z = z.trim();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.trim()` at the end. :p

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - I'd other suggestion though! Nevertheless, added your suggestion too!:)

Comment: `-1` if you are **sure** that there is no space before `Patient`.